# How to do JSON marshalling in tcl?

Tags: json, tcl, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to create a JSON for one of our requirement, I want to do JSON marshelling in my Tcl script, Is there any way to do the same in Tcl. Any solution with example will be more useful.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [json::write](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/tcllib/json/json_write.html) package in Tcllib is recommended, but it's pretty primitive.

```
package require json::write

set abc {This is an example with "quotes" in it}
set pqr "yet another string"
set stu "and another"
puts [json::write object abc [json::write string $abc] def [
    json::write array \
       123 \
       [json::write string $pqr] \
       [json::write string $stu]
]]
```

That produces this output when I try it:

```
{
    "abc" : "This is an example with \"quotes\" in it",
    "def" : [123,"yet another string","and another"]
}
```

You can also use the (evil, type-aware) technique described on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/JSON#Tcl); that builds on top of the json::write package (now that I've rewritten it…) and lets you do:

```
puts [tcl2json [dict create "abc" $abc "def" [list 123 $pqr $stu]]]
```

to generate the same output.

Comment: That `tcl2json` code _requires_ Tcl 8.6; it can't be backported. If you're using 8.5, you're stuck with writing out everything in full. (Don't use 8.4 and before.)